# Re: How Do I Make A Count For The Amount Of Times A Certain URL Was Open From A Different Web View?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I changed up the question because the last question wasn't clear enough.

I want to implement this for the amount of times a certain URL was open. I need the count for when a certain URL is opened from another URL that I set in a UIWebView.  Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
.h: 
int Number;

.m: 
Number += 10;
Label.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d”, Number];
```

Comment: Run the code in your example, `Number += 10;`, whenever the certain URL is opened in your app.

Comment: Yea I want to put this code with the URL. How can this be done?

Comment: It depends, what is your URL endpoint? Is it a GET or POST? If it's a get, just do [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?times_opened=%d",URL,Number];. If it's a POST, then put it in the URL body. This isn't the best way though - honestly the server should be keeping track of this metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like the following:

```
- (void)openURL:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *url = //URL;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    Number += 1;
    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Number];
}
```

Comment: Check out the OP's comment - he also wants to pass Number on the URL.

Comment: This answers the question he posted. If he meant something else he'll change his question.

Comment: He's new to SO so I was cutting him some slack. Just trying to help him out.

Comment: Ok. I just don't really understand the question and was being difficult. If he changes the question I'll change my answer.

Comment: My answer should be it then.

Comment: With a few changes, I was able to figure it out.